# How to display an image in an MDI Tab, MFC Application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, mdi

For normal Window dialogs in the win api, im used to getting the Device Context (DC) and using that to paint graphics on the specific window. However, I can't find any way to access the DC for the MDI tab. Do they have an alternative to DC's.

The function from the sdk im using (Global Mapper) to draw the image requires the DC to display the image. Incase you need it, the function im using is listed below.

```
GM_Error_t32 GM_DrawLayer
(
HDC                     aDC,            // Device context to draw to
GM_LayerHandle_t32      aLayer,         // Layer to draw or NULL for all
const GM_Rectangle_t*   aWorldBounds,   // World bounds to draw or NULL for all
sint32                  aLeftPixel,     // Left pixel coordinate to draw to
sint32                  aTopPixel,      // Top pixel coordinate to draw to
sint32                  aPixelWidth,    // Width in pixels to draw
sint32                  aPixelHeight    // Height in pixels to draw
);
```

Comment: If you really have an MFC MDI application, then each tab should be an instance of a `CMDIChildWnd`, which in turn should contain one or more views. Everything drawable should have a DC. What exactly do you mean when you say "MDI tab"? What class are we talking about?

Comment: CMDIFrameWndEx, when i get the DC from it though, it displays the image to the whole window, not just the tab.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165830.aspx - MDI Tabbed Group

Comment: Ok, then look at the example code in the Remarks section [of this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs0t7t34.aspx) (ignore the fact that it's via a base class).

Comment: brilliant that works, thanks! :)

Comment: Cool - glad I could help.